# Moving Custom solutions in SP 2010 to new SP 2013 Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, migration, solution-deployment

How can we successfully deploy/move all custom solutions (custom visual web parts, event receivers, custom workflows, Administrative Full-Trust InfoPath forms, etc.) developed for SharePoint 2010 to new SharePoint 2013 farm. What points should I consider before and after moving these custom solutions to new SharePoint 2013 farm.

Comment: Is the information in my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compile/build a project that originated from Visual Studio 2010, I had to install and configure “Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012” in order to open the projects in Visual Studio 2012.

The following link describes how to download and install “Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012”.

[How to enable SharePoint 2013 Development Project Templates in Visual Studio 2012](http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2013/03/18/articlehow-to-enable-sharepoint-2013-development-project-templates-in-visual-studio-2012/)

To update solutions for SharePoint 2013 you need to follow some steps to do changes in your custom codes mentioned in below link.

[How to Migrate a SharePoint 2010 Solution to 2013](http://www.threewill.com/how-to-migrate-a-sharepoint-2010-solution-to-2013/)